# Connect to rails server remotely from raspberry pi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, connection, raspberry-pi

I have ssh'd into my rasberry pi and built a rails application.

Now how do I load the rails app from another machine?

I have tried IP:port in a web browser, but this fails.

Can I use ssh from a web browser to load the rails server process?

Are there gems I need to install to do this?

Is there any good documentation that I have missed?

**SOLUTION**

use ngrok to tunnel https://medium.com/@karimbutt/using-ngrok-to-create-a-publicly-accessible-web-facing-raspberry-pi-server-35deef8c816a#.sraso7zar

Comment: i don't have any experience with this, but I wonder if running `ngrok` or `localtunnel` on the pi would help if it is connected to the internet?

Comment: Are you running it with Webrick on port 3000? The rpi needs to be accepting connections on that port - which means you can't be blocking them with iptables. In most default configurations, iptables won't be blocking anything on the rpi. Is the server services listening on all interfaces, or only on the loopback 127.0.0.1? It must be listening on the rpi's external network interface.

Comment: @maxpleaner that worked! ngrok! added solution to post

Comment: @heyzuse cool. i just posted an answer. accepting that will mark the question answered, unless you want to keep it open and see if anyone else has a better idea.

Comment: @heyzuse out of curiosity what's your pi app do? I think IoT gadgets are so cool. By the way, michael berkowski's advice sounds like the more advanced configuration method. Might be beneficial in the long term to learn.

Comment: @maxpleaner it's a super simple ecommerce website. It's for a university project. The university linux servers don't work well with Rails, and I didn't want to pay for hosting. I always knew that raspberry pi would come in handy one day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is with the IP address you're trying to use. Servers don't necessarily forward their public IP traffic to localhost automatically.

Perhaps you could configure the IP address somehow, I don't know (others might?). Alternatively, you have a use a "local tunnel" service like [ngrok](http://ngrok.com) or [localtunnel](http://localtunnel.me). What these do is create a public URL for your localhost (i.e. your "loopback" address), so anyone can access it.

I spoke with a Ngrok author via email. He ensured me that I shouldn't need to expect any downtime from the service or to have to manually restart it. Although keep in mind that if you're on the free plan, whenever you restart Ngrok you're going to get a different URL. He also described it as kind of like a "souped up SSH -R"